# Solve penetration issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, penetration-testing

I have this function to count the number of Admin user in data Base and the ConnexionString is the string connexion to database: (the count to check if he can add a new Admin)

```
if (UserController.CountUsers(Level.Admin, ActiveUser.ConnexionString) >5)
{
    user.Message = "You reach the max of Admin!";
    return RedirectToAction("EditUser");
}
```

And in the asp page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var erreur = $("#Message").val();

if (erreur.length > 0) {
    jAlert(error, 'Error', false);
}
</script>
```

And I got this complaint: (test by IBM Security AppScan)

> Blind SQL Injection  Severity: High
>
> Entities: Message (Parameter)
>
> Risk: You can view, edit, or delete database entries and tables
>
> Cause: The correction of risky characters was not performed correctly
>
> Difference: Parameter manipulated
>
> from: You reach the max of Admin!
>
> To: % 27 +% 2B + ltrim% 28% 27% 27% 29 +% 2B +%27You+reach+the+max+of+++Admin!21%

Can I fix that!

Comment: _"The correction of risky characters was not performed correctly"_ gives me one Google hit: this question. Did you translate it? What tool are you using, what exactly is it testing, how does it do so, and is it correct in its statement?

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry I got this complaint from the client (I don't Know what app he use)

Comment: Looks like it could be AppScan.. IMO, the issue appears to be a false positive. There's nothing wrong with the input `"You reach the max of Admin!"`, if you were constructing this from user input you would want to sanitize it which is what the error is warning about. But since you aren't doing this, is it really an issue?

Comment: Then try to ask the client that. We can't tell from this code and that error what is the issue. I see no user input in the function (where do `Level.Admin` and `ActiveUser.ConnexionString` come from, and what does the `CountUsers()` method look like?) and no output that would reveal table structure or output arbitrary records.

Comment: Is the message saved on the server? It seems that if they change the value of message it is save on the server and they can save the value from the To. It looks like the error/problem is caused somewhere else.

Comment: @CodeCaster I update my question for the CountUsers, and for the Message I just Show it to user to Know that he can't add another Admin

Comment: @CodeCaster the client use IBM Security AppScan